# Accessing a new browser tab using classic-watir

Tags: watir

In my app, when you click on some links, they open the url in a new tab.  I'm having trouble trying to access the new tab.

I've tried using `send_keys` but haven't been able to get that to work.  I'm using classic-watir (1.9.0), not watir-webdriver.   Unfortunately, whenever I try to search on this, I get many results referencing watir-webdriver but none referencing classic watir.

I know at some point I should upgrade to watir-webdriver, but at the moment, I really don't have the time to upgrade all my tests.

Comment: There's really no need to upgrade from watir-classic to watir-webdriver if you really just need to run your tests against IE. watir-classic is not deprecated or not maintained, it is just classic :)

Answer (score 1):

Attaching to tabs is the same as attaching to windows.

You can `attach` to the new tab:

```
ie2 = Watir::IE.attach(:title, 'new_windows_title')
ie2.close   #close the new tab
```

Or can use the `window` or `windows` method (note that this will work in both watir-classic and watir-webdriver):

```
#Close the last opened tab
ie.windows.last.use do
  ie.close
end

#Close a specific tab
ie.window(:title => 'new_windows_title').use do
  ie.close
end
```

Comment: when I use .windows or .window, I get undefined method.  I'm running old versions of Ruby (0.9.4) and Watir (1.9.0).  Do I need to upgrade to access this method?

Comment: Yes, I believe those are in a newer version. If you are on 1.9, I believe you would have to stick with the attach method.